# Styling list hierarchy side by side

Tags: css, nested-lists

I'm trying to think of the best way to set up a list so that each ul is on the same physical height level on the page. So, for example if I have:

```
<ul>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2
        <ul>
            <li>2.1</li>
            <li>2.2</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>3</li>
</ul>
```

it would show up as:

```
1   2.1
2   2.2
3
```

The only method that I've come up with is absolute positioning each `<ul>` to the top of a relatively positioned container, but I want the container to maintain the size of its children. I've been brainstorming for a while, and haven't come up with a good solution. If I `float` them, or `display:inline-block;`, each subset list will inherit the top of its parent, so it would show up like:

```
1
2   2.1
3   2.2
```

That being said... help!

Comment: What should happen if you had a "3.1" section?

Comment: It would stack on top of the 2.1, 2.2 section, if all works well.

Comment: Please could you update with an example?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/EcQRb/ but what I'm looking for is something that will allow the parent to not require a fixed height if overflow is hidden.

Answer (score 0):

Looks incredibly tricky. Is there a reason the data cannot be separated into two lists that are not connected by child-parent relationship? maybe even using some javascript to pull out the child lists on the client side.

something similar to this in jQuery:

```
var childLists = $("ul > li > ul");
$(".listsContainer").append(childLists);
$("ul > li > ul").remove();
```

And then just use some basic css to move the new lists into position, probably best to 'append' them into their own sub container to make stacking on top of each other easier.

**edit:** working example http://jsfiddle.net/3HqxL/ (css does not have to be in javascript)

Comment: I'm looking to create a megamenu for sitemap navigation, to make it somewhat dynamic. And I'm searching for a CSS option for now. Thanks though!

Comment: See my edit for an example, the list is still supplied in the exact same way, and javascript strips it out on the client side and positions. Not the most elegant way, but it does work!

Comment: It's a thought. Still looking for a CSS method though! If I'm using JS, I may as well just use my CSS method and set the height of the parent with JS.

Comment: I'm not sure if what your after is possible in css, not to my knowledge at least, as each sub list would need to be able to calculate the height of the sub list before it to stack properly, and they are not directly on top of each other in the DOM so I'm not sure if that is doable.

Comment: Yeah, that was my thinking, but I wanted to check in here before I declared it a no-go.

Comment: @Torr3nt Man, you really are after a css-based solution. Personally, I don't think this is possible. But I'd not lose hope without a fight :D

Answer (score 0):

Posting the entire code here.
Edited your html slightly.

```
<ul class="menu">
    <li><span>1</span></li>
    <li><span>2</span>
        <ul class="sub_menu">
            <li>2.1</li>
            <li>2.2</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><span>3</span></li>
</ul>​
```

You can edit the css (background-color,color,width etc to suit your needs)

```
.menu li span{
    display:block;
    float:left;
    width: 20px;
    background-color:#ddd;
    padding:2px;
}
.menu li ul{
    float:left;
}

.menu ul li{
    padding:2px;
    float:left;
    margin:0px 5px;
    background-color:#eee;
}

.menu ul{
    clear:right;
    overflow:auto;    
}

.menu > li{
    clear:both;
    background-color:#ccc;
    overflow:auto;
    width:100px;
}
​
```

Here is a link to JSFIDDLE AS WELL
http://jsfiddle.net/zTygm/1

Comment: Not quite the functionality I'm looking for. I want this functionality (http://jsfiddle.net/EcQRb/) via a method that allows the parent to maintain space.

Comment: Nope, still not quite it! Each #1 link (1, 1.1, 3.2.1, etc) will be on the first row, #2 will be on the second row, etc.

Comment: @Torr3nt is that even intuitive ? that kind of link placement ? Let me give it a shot anyway :)

Comment: It is for the sort of functionality I'm looking for. Trust me :)